# Evaluating arithmetic circuits with stochastic rounding

Tags: randomized-algorithms

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $y = f(x_i)$ be an arithmetic circuit in the $x_i$'s.  That is, $f$ is a circuit of negate, add, subtract, and multiply gates.  Let $X_i$ be floating point random variables with $E(X_i) = x_i$, and let $Y$ be the result of evaluating $f(X_i)$ using [stochastic rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Stochastic_rounding) to the two nearest floating point numbers at every step.  That is, at each step we evaluate $\operatorname{op}(a,b)$ in infinite precision, then randomly choose one of the two neighboring floating point values so that the mean choice is the exact answer.

**Informal question:** If we sample many times from $Y$, can we get a PAC estimate of $y$ from the sample mean and variance?

Here's why I think this might be doable, at least in some cases:

1. [Connolly et al. 2021, Stochastic rounding and its probabilistic backward error analysis](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/20M1334796?download=true) show that if the circuit $f$ is a tree, the errors at each step are mean independent (mean zero conditional on previous errors).  They use this to derive backward error estimates that are roughly as good as assuming the errors are entirely independent.
2. If $f$ is linear, then $E(Y) = y$.
3. The first problem where mean independence breaks is squaring: $E(X^2) \ne E(X)^2$.  However, if $X = x(1 + E)$ with $|E| \le \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \ll 0$, then
   $$X^2 = x^2(1+2E+E^2) = x^2(1+2E) + O(\epsilon^2)$$
   Ideally, this would mean that if the circuit $f$ has low multiplication depth, the linear error term dominates the distribution of $Y$, and that term is mean zero.

The circuit I'm interested in is not particularly stable, so I don't expect to be able to prove anything about its error properties.  So the ideal would be to be able to read off an accuracy estimate from samples from $Y$.  Unfortunately, the "non-mean-zero term is small" intuition from (3) might be impossible to detect from the distribution of $Y$.

**More precise question:** Say we sample $y_1, \ldots, y_n \sim Y$, and fix $\lambda > 1$.  Can we bound the probability $p$ s.t. $y \in [m-\lambda s, m+\lambda s]$, where $m = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i y_i, s = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i (y_i-m)^2$ are the sample mean and variance?

**Floating point details:** I'm happy to ignore exponent overflow/underflow, so we can take as our representable floating point values $\mathbb{F} = \{0\} \cup \pm\{2^{p-1}, \ldots, 2^p-1\} 2^\mathbb{Z}$ for some bit precision $p \in \mathbb{N}$ ($p = 53$ for double precision).  We can assume oracle access to $X_i$, either because $x_i \in \mathbb{F}$ or because we are given a routine to sample each $X_i$.

Comment: Maybe [this chaotic quadratic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) would be a good candidate for a counter-example?  E.g. have one input $x_1$, define $f_0(x_1)=x_1$ and define $f_n(z) = 4 f_{n-1}(z)(1-f_{n-1}(z))$.  This is chaotic so for large enough $n$ you will have $|f_n(1/3+\epsilon) - f_n(1/3-\epsilon)|$ being large even for very small $\epsilon$.  Evaluating in python on my machine with $n=200$ I see $f_n(2^{-50}) \approx 0.16722033851971366$, while $f_n(2^{-51}) \approx 0.8150761827512897$.  And of course $f_n(0)=0$.

Comment: @NealYoung: But wouldn't that produce large variance in $Y$?  The question is roughly whether, if $\operatorname{var}(Y)$ is small, one can conclude we have a good estimate for $y$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see what you mean.  A bad example would have to be tightly concentrated, but around the wrong answer.  Try iterating the map $f(x) = -0.23 x^3 - 0.54 x^2 + 1.77x$.  It should have $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, and iterating starting at $x=0.001$ or $x=-0.001$, say (very near 0) should converge to 1 instead of 0.  So probably this can be converted into a counterexample (by scaling so that the fixed point 0 is moved to, say, 1/3, which is not representable, then each sample of $f_n(1/3)$ (the $n$th iteration of $f$, for large but fixed $n$) should be near 1, even though $f_n(1/3) = 1/3$.

Comment: For the lazy, [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+-0.23x%5E3-0.54x%5E2%2B1.77x%2C+x&client=safari&rls=en&sxsrf=APq-WBsGQvPVabPizM7KC7Uxtix8mvfWyA%3A1643948735303&ei=v6r8YfaEEqaCwbkP0oyPgAc&ved=0ahUKEwi24JWjmuX1AhUmQTABHVLGA3AQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=plot+-0.23x%5E3-0.54x%5E2%2B1.77x%2C+x&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAM6BwgAEEcQsANKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQqAtY-lBgilhoAXACeACAAeIBiAGsB5IBBTYuMi4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) is a plot of $f(x) = -0.23x^3 - 0.54x^2+1.77x$.

Comment: @NealYoung: That's a nice idea!  It does seem like that sinks the hope of reading off accuracy from just the final answer.  In that example the computation would still be backward stable, but plausibly one could a variant with a slightly higher degree polynomial that doesn't get backward stability either.